# Crystal oscillator ECS-2520MV connection

Tags: capacitor, oscillator, crystal

First time connecting this type of oscillator and need some help as too how to connect it. The oscillator I will be using is the https://ecsxtal.com/store/pdf/ECS-2520MV.pdf [image]

Does this seem correct to you?

---

**Edit after receiving guidance from answers**

So now I seem to understand a bit better now and this is what I have come up with. Since the component does not require ceramic capacitors and only one output with the tri state to make active. This is it?

[image]

Comment: We cannot know if that is correct, because you don't say which chip that is that needs the clock. We can't even say if it  can accept 3.3V square wave at all, it might get damaged if that is too much voltage. Please add this info to the question.

Comment: Hi there this is the chip https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001803A.pdf I assume it will take 3.3V since that is the voltage I would like to drive it.

Comment: It depends what kind of clock source the chip is configured to expect. The example diagram shows a 8 MHz crystal. And you have chosen a 2 MHz oscillator. How can you know it will work with it? At least the 8MHz crystal is needed for USB interface, and it is said that no external clock is required if USB is not used. If you need a clock source, why can't you simply use the 8 MHz crystal as suggested?

Comment: Hi there I actually have the 8Mhz version of the crystal. Should I look for a crystal oscillator that has a crystal and 2 capacitors instead of this component?

Answer (score 1):

> *Does this seem correct to you?*

The top line of the linked data sheet says this: -

> **The ECS-2520MV is a miniature SMD HCMOS Oscillator with MultiVolt
> capability of 1.6 ~ 3.6 V.**

In other words, you feed the module with a power supply between 1.6 volts and 3.6 volts and, it produces an output signal that can be fed into the oscillator input on your chip. It is not a crystal and doesn't require 15 pF capacitors connected as you have shown.

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks a lot of the feedback and yes I think I understand now. Would you happen to sketch me how I should connect it please? I am finding it hard to find an example of the connection. Thank you

Comment: @MateuszW if you [take the two minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) you'll find out what motivates people to give free help on this site. Then, look at your earlier question and do what is expected of you.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look and further how I can help contribute to the community. Sorry if caused any problems.

Comment: No problems have been caused. Not everyone coming to this site are aware.

Comment: Hi Andy, sorry to bother you but is it appropriate to share my new layout based on understanding? I just don't want to share false information.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean (at all).

Answer (score 0):

It definitely looks wrong.

You either use a quartz crystal and connect it to MCU clock pins like a quartz crystals should be connected, or you use a crystal oscillator and connect it to power supplies and MCU clock pin like a crystal oscillator should be connected.

Don't mix and match uncompatible components and their connections.